# Register Startup Script Control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, controls

I am looking to make a web control where I can register client startup scripts inline with my aspx because I hate registering in the codebehind!

An example of what I have so far:

```
<Ben:StartupScript runat="server">

    var form = document.getElementById("<% =form1.ClientID %>");

</Ben:StartupScript>
```

Currently, I am overriding the `OnPreRender` method of the control, rendering the contents of the control to a string and then manually registering that string as a  startup script using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` on the `Page`. I also override the `Render` method in order not to render the control. I should also note that I have the `ParseChildren` attribute set to `false` and the `PersistChildren` attribute set to `true`.

All seems to be working well, but my control allows other web controls inside it (such as Button). Apart from being unintuitive, this can result in runtime errors. I would love to be able to clear the controls but this is impossible given the `<% ... %>` code block.

So, is it possible to prevent developers from embedding child controls whilst still allowing code blocks?

Also, is this idea any good or is it fundamentally flawed? Lol.

Thanks a bunch,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like a good idea, but if you spend too much time fighting the inherited/default behaviors then it may be more trouble than it's worth

if this is a one-shot issue, a cheap-hack solution is to just directly embed your scripts in the header of a master page ;-)

on the other hand, allowing developers to embed their own scripts as children of your web control might be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are using master pages, add another  control in your  section. That way you can easily add css/js to your headers in your child pages.

ClientScript.RegisterScript is mostly for user/server controls,